# Sanitizing strings with filenames and extension in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Having this four type of file names:

1. Filename with double extension
2. Filename with no extension
3. Filename with dot at the end, and no extension
4. Filename with a proper name.

Like this:

```
String doubleexsension = "doubleexsension.pdf.pdf";
String noextension = "noextension";
String nameWithDot = "nameWithDot.";
String properName = "properName.pdf";

String extension = "pdf";
```

My aim is to sanitze all the types and output only the `filename.filetype` properly. I made a little stupid script in order to make this post:

```
ArrayList<String> app = new ArrayList<String>();
app.add(doubleexsension);
app.add(properName);
app.add(noextension);
app.add(nameWithDot);

System.out.println("------------");

for(String i : app) {

    // Ends with .
    if (i.endsWith(".")) {
        String m = i + extension;
        System.out.println(m);
        break;
    }

    // Double extension
    String p = i.replaceAll("(\\.\\w+)\\1+$", "$1");
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

This outputs:

```
------------
doubleexsension.pdf
properName.pdf
noextension
nameWithDot.pdf
```

I dont know how can I handle the `noextension` one. How can I do it? When there's no extension, it should take the `extension` value and apped it to the string at the end.

My desired output would be:

```
------------
doubleexsension.pdf
properName.pdf
noextension.pdf
nameWithDot.pdf
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  `doubleexsension.pdf` is a valid filename (no extension). Just because it has an "extra" extension means nothing special, really. You could treat that case the exact same as a single extension

Comment: How you want to make the decision that `doubleexsension.pdf.pdf` is `doubleexsension.pdf` and `doubleexsension.foo.pdf` is `doubleexsension.foo`?

Comment: `if (! i.endsWith("."+extension)) { // add extension }`

Comment: @SubOptimal That's why OP used the regex `(\\.\\w+)\\1+$` - that detects a repetition of the same extension.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Yes, I didn't look at the OP's regex properly. You are right. He probably wants only repeating extensions to be removed

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right. Didn't check the code, as it was not explained in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add alternatives to the regex to match all kinds of scenarios:

```
(?:(\.\w+)\1*|\.|([^.]))$
```

And replace with `$2.pdf`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftAncS/1).

**EDIT**: In case the extensions that can be duplicated are known, you may use the whitelisting approach via an alternation group:

```
(?:(\.(?:pdf|gif|jpe?g))\1*|\.|([^.]))$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftAncS/3).

**Details**:

- `(?:` - start of grouping, the `$` end of string anchor is applied to all the alternatives below (they must be at the end of string)

  - `(\.\w+)\1*` - duplicated (or not) extensions (`.` + 1+ word chars repeated zero or more times) (with the whitelisting approach, only the indicated extensions will be taken into account - `(?:pdf|gif|jpe?g)` will only match `pdf`, `gif`, jpeg`, jpg`, etc. if more alternatives are added)
  - `|` - or
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `|` - or
  - `([^.])` - any char that is not a dot captured into Group 2
- `)` - end of the outer grouping
- `$` - end of string.

See  [Java demo](http://ideone.com/MGHlWd):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("doubleexsension.pdf.pdf","noextension","nameWithDot.","properName.pdf");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?:(\\.\\w+)\\1*|\\.|([^.]))$", "$2.pdf"));
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly and I accepted the answer. I just found the filenames can have the name as follows: `HEY HELLO._1995`. This would be a filename without extension but has that `._1995`. Is there a way to scape this kind of strings without a white list of extensions?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to exclude `_` from the extensions? If you know there can be no `_` in them, use `(?:(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\1*|\.|([^.]))$` (or `(?:(\.\p{Alnum}+)\1*|\.|([^.]))$`). Else, you will need to list the whitelisted extensions within an alternation group - [`(?:(\.(?:pdf|gif|jpe?g))\1*|\.|([^.]))$`](https://regex101.com/r/ftAncS/3)

Comment: There is an edge case. `foo.foo` becomes `foo.pdf`. Might be not the expected result.

Comment: @SubOptimal: No, if the https://regex101.com/r/ftAncS/4 is used. I updated the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice. I believe it would be better to add this to the answer instead into a comment.

Comment: @SubOptimal I added that right below the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
if (-1 == i.indexOf('.'))
    System.out.println(i + "." + extension);
```

Comment: Only cover second case.

Comment: yep. I intended only to cover the case when no extension, so this was meant to be inserted into the end of the loop. However, regex is the king, though they require practice to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the complexity (and reduced readability) of regular expressions:

```
String m = i;

if (m.endsWith(".")) {
    m = m + extension;
}
if (m.endsWith("." + extension + "." + extension)) {
    m = m.substring(0, m.length() - extension.length() - 1);
}
if (!m.endsWith("." + extension)) {
    m = m + "." + extension;
}
```

Comment: +1 It would also avoid having to think about the different behaviors of different regex engines (regardless of whether in this quite simple case at its current stage this would be an issue or not).

Answer (score 0):

Why so complex. Just do `str.replaceAll("\\..*", "") + "." + extension`

Comment: Because the OP seems to want something like The.Moon.Rise.pdf to stay as it is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic didn't think about it.

Answer (score -1):

Java 7 NIO has a way to do this by using PathMatcher

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.pdf");

Path filename = namewithdot.pdf;
if (matcher.matches(filename)) {
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Comment: Read question carefully. It is not about how to filter names.